# CKEditor insert widget into other widget

Tags: plugins, widget, ckeditor

I have problem with widgets in CKEditor 4.3. How to allow widget insert other widget?

For example:

First widget has title and content. Second widget has left panel and right panel. How I can put second widget into first widget?

Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer, because since CKEditor 4.5.0 Beta it is possible to nest widgets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible yet. We had to block possibility to nest widgets while working on first Widget System implementation in CKEditor 4.3.

I [reported a ticket](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10931) for this feature. However, it may take a few major releases to remove this limitation, since it's a very complex thing.

**Edit**: Since [CKEditor 4.5.0 Beta](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.5-Beta-Released) it is possible to nest widgets. If you want to test it quickly please check [CKEditor 4.5 insert widget into other widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816581/ckeditor-4-5-insert-widget-into-other-widget/29841881#29841881).

Comment: And now how do you *prevent* a specific widget from nesting in another specific widget?  Or a widget from being nested in another instance of the same widget?