# CKEditor 4.5 insert widget into other widget

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

CKEditor 4.5 Beta now should allow nested widgets.
http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.5-Beta-Released

Can you help me to figure out how can I test nested widgets?
I've downloaded 4.5 Beta, created a SimpleBox widget by instructions in tutorial (but without 'allowedContent' filters). But I still cannot put one widget inside editable of another. Can you clarify what I'm doing wrong or point me to correct example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to test nested widgets will be by checking a sample that I created for development purposes. It's stripped from the packages, so you will need to clone the repo.

```
git clone https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev.git
git co major
```

And then see this file: [`ckeditor-dev/plugins/widget/dev/nestedwidgets.html`](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/widget/dev/nestedwidgets.html).

It's nothing more than the image2 and placeholder plugins running together with the simplebox. You can also check simplebox inside simplebox inside simplebox inside simplebox... ;)

Comment: Do you have any idea why nesting would not work? I installed the simplebox plugin, in the repo it worked for me, in my local installation using CKEditor it doesnt (4.5.1)

Comment: Perhaps ACF settings for the nested editables. IIRC in the tutorial the setting is pretty strict.

Comment: what to you mean by `IIRC in the tutorial the setting` ?

Comment: I meant that "If I remember correctly, in the [tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1) the [allowed content setting of nested editable](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1-section-limiting-available-formatting) is very strict, so e.g. it does not allow anything else than simple formatting. You need to extend that setting to allow another simple box to be inserted into another one.