# Why does CKEditor's nesting widgets not work in my Drupal build?

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I was very excited to read that nesting widgets is now possible with CKE 4.4+. I read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816581/ckeditor-4-5-insert-widget-into-other-widget/29841881#29841881) and tried it out - wonderful. Strangely, it does not work with my Drupal site using the CKEditor module.

So, what I got:

The module uses the CDN, delivering CKE 4.5.1 (//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.1/full-all).
I set up a module to provide the simplebox plugin (taken from the working dev repo example):

```
function mymodule_ckeditor_plugin() {
  $plugins = array();
  $plugins['simplebox'] = array(
    'name' => 'simplebox',
    'desc' => t('simplebox Plugin'),
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/plugins/simplebox/',
    'buttons' => array(
      'Simplebox' => array('label' => 'Simplebox', 'icon' => 'icons/simplebox.png'),
    )
  );
  return $plugins;
}
```

which offers me the plugin to activate:

[image]
[image]

And the plugin button is available on my toolbar:
[image]

Clicking it, the markup gets created. But strangely, adding another one, nested inside, is not possible:

[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure where did you get the Simplebox plugin from. I assume that you downloaded it from the official ["Creating a Simple CKEditor Widget (Part 2)"](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_2) guide.

If so, I got to tell you that there's a minor difference between the plugin attached to the guide and that one in `plugins/widget/dev/assets/simplebox/plugin.js` in [ckeditor-dev](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev) repository.

The later is up–to–date and enables any kind of rich HTML within `content` nested editable:

```
editor.widgets.add( 'simplebox', {
    ...
    editables: {
        ...
        content: {
            selector: '.simplebox-content'
        }
    }   
} );
```

while the old is very restrictive:

```
editor.widgets.add( 'simplebox', {
    ...
    editables: {
        ...
        content: {
            selector: '.simplebox-content',
            allowedContent: 'p br ul ol li strong em'
        }
    }   
} );
```

See [API docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.nestedEditable.definition) to know more about the definition of nested editables. The introduction to [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_deep_dive) in CKEditor should also prove helpful.

**The solution**: copy [simplebox plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/master/plugins/widget/dev/assets/simplebox) from the GitHub repository and enjoy nested widgets, with drag and drop, etc. Or just remove `allowedContent` restriction from `content` nested editable.

And sorry for the inconvenience, we're doing our best to keep our documentation up–to–date but it's such a massive task that sometimes we're unable to catch up ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually took the simplebox plugin from the dev repo, thats why I initally created the question :)

Comment: I updated my question accordingly. I feel like the drupal loaded CKEditor misses some features, altough I have set `"//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.1/full-all"` as CDN source. Is there any way I can test whether some plugin is missing that is required to nest widgets?

Comment: @Alex: Are you completely sure that your Simplebox plugin is up–to–date? Could you post the contents of `plugin.js` as GitHub Gist?

Comment: The code in the gist is up–to–date. That's strange. Are you sure `CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.plugins.simplebox.path` points to the latest version of the plugin? Cache cleared? Does the `CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.widgets.registered.simplebox.editables.content` equal `Object {selector: ".simplebox-content"}`?

Comment: path is correct, the object says:  `Object {selector: ".simplebox-content"}` - cache cleared all the time, trying different browsers - nothing works

Comment: Just done a clean installation of Drupal 7.38 and it WFM http://i.imgur.com/CZrCOUt.png. Any chance of live demo?

Comment: live demo not, but I can try to make a fresh install also. Did you use the ckeditor module? What version? Which CDN source?

Comment: Downloaded and installed https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor, set the "Path to CKEditor" to `//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.1/full-all`, copy&pasted your `mymodule_ckeditor_plugin()`, created dummy info file, copied `simplebox` from `ckeditor-dev` GitHub repo to `modules/mymodule/plugins`. That's all.

Comment: Did you use the dev version or the stable release of the drupal module?

Comment: The dev version of the module (7.x.1.x-dev @ 2015-Apr-01) actually works for me, unfortunately its not "stable". Do you have any idea what difference may cause this?

Comment: Did you change the path to `//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.1/full-all` in "CKEditor Global profile"?

Comment: As I stated, of course :) `CKEditor.version` always returned the latest version, even with the old module (which has actually nothing to do with the lib itself, but the source was always set to 4.5.1 full)

Comment: Your answer didnt quite solve my problem but thanks for your effort :)

Comment: @Alex The bounty makes it feel like Christmas ;)

Comment: I believe so :) Not for me, though :P